# Solr - Is there a way to speed up my import

Tags: search, solr, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I have a relational database model 
This is the basics of my data-config.xml

```
<entity name="MyMainEntity" pk="pID" query="select ... from [dbo].[TableA] inner join TableB on ...">
    <entity name="Entity1" pk="Id1" query="SELECT [Text] Tag from [Table2] where ResourceId = '${MyMainEntity.pId}'"></entity>
            <entity name="Entity1" pk="Id2" query="SELECT [Text] Tag from [Table2] where ResourceId2 = '${MyMainEntity.pId}'"></entity>
    <entity name="LibraryItem" pk="ResourceId" 
            query="select SKU
                    FROM [TableB] 
                    INNER JOIN ...
                    ON ...
                    INNER JOIN ...
                    ON ...
                    WHERE ... AND ...'">
    </entity>
</entity>
```

Now, this takes a lot of time.
10000 rows in the first query and then each other inner entities are fetched later (around 10 rows each).

If I use a db profiler I see a the three inner entities query running over and over (3 select sentences than again 3 select sentences over and over)
This is really not efficient.
And the import can run over 40 hrs ()
Now,
What are my options to run it faster .

1. Obviously there is an option to flat the tables to one big table - but that will create a lot of other side effects. I would really like to avoid that extra effort and run solr on my production relational tables.
   So far it works great out of the box and I am searching here if there is a configuration tweak.
2. If I will flat the rows that - does the schema.xml need to be change too? or the same fields that are multivalued will keep being multivalued.

Thanks.

Comment: If they are single sub entity, how about building a view over the tables instead of firing multiple queries ? that is much much faster

Comment: Generating a view will force me to generate another primary key (because of the multiplication) I would like to avoid it as much as I can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without changing the schema of the DB, the first thing to try is [caching](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#CachedSqlEntityProcessor). If the inner entities cache well, gains will be substantial.

Maybe the wiki is not uptodate so you should check the jira issues, namely [solr-2382](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2382) and maybe have a look at [solr-2948](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2948) too.

A second path could be trying multithreading DIH, but it's more tricky. At one point this was optional, but later was removed cause it was buggy, and I think now there was some jira issue trying to reimplement it, try look it up, but I recommend caching first.